Distance between two multivariate distributions

I have data structured as followed: 2 years -> several metrics per year (let's say 2000) -> several measurements per metric (let's say 1000 for year 1 and 800 for year 2). So I have a 2000x1000 for year 1 and 2000x800 for year 2 datasets. I want a measure of similarity or distance between the two years that takes into account all metrics and the distribution for each measurements, knowing that some measurements are related. I know there are many ways to think about this problem. I would like a solution that takes into account the distribution of each metrics without having to average each.
The different ideas I have so far are:
MANOVA
Distribution distance metric by metric (Kolmogorov-Smirnov or something of the like) and then aggregating all (by averaging). Working with Python in case anyone has a package suggestion.
Thank you!

Look into the energy distance and maximum mean discrepancy. The energy distance can be used to perform a test called DISCO that is like an omnibus test for the difference between two multivariate distributions between groups.

If the metrics are correlated you may simplify the problem a bit by considering a distance between the first most relevant principal scores.

If all you want is to measure the difference between the distributions, the Energy Distance would be a good option. (Looks like @Noah beat me to the punch with the e-dist recommendation!)
